# Convert index to percentage

Tags: dividends, equity

How would you convert the equity premium risk to percentage found here: https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/indices/strategy/sp-us-equity-risk-premium-index/#overview

Answer (score 1):

Simply the change from 16th Feb 2022 to 16th Feb 2023.

```
176.90/160.87 - 1 = 9.96457 %
```

[image]

Comment: I was wondering will this give the equity risk premium or just the  percentage index change? for instance if i look at 16th of Feb 2023 the index level is 196.9, from this how do i convert it into a equity risk premium percentage? since i would like to have the equity risk premium at a point in time